# Shnayim Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty two?

### שנים ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 332? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 332, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

If you step up and put on your detective hat, I'm sure you can come up with something better than lazy gematria.

Comment: There are 3 lazy gematriays for 332. You used all 3 in the last sentence. Oy gevalt.

Comment: @Cnsersmoit, I think there are one or two more that I didn't use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I know the community does not generally like Gematrias, however I felt this one was worth it.

The Rashei Taivos of Shema Yisrael Hashem Elokeinu Hashem Echad = 332 (ש' י' י' א' י' א'). The [last public speech](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35432&st=&pgnum=22&hilite=) of the Ahavas Yisrael of Vishnitz was on Lag B'Omer 5696. He passed away shortly thereafter on 2 Sivan 5696. At that speech he mentioned how Kabolas Ol Malchus Shamayim is a requirement to accepting the Torah. On Lag B'Omer where there was a Hisgalus of the light Torah it is the Midah of Hod Shebihod הוד שבהוד. The Gematria of הוד שבהוד is also 332. This connection shows that we accepted upon us on Lag B'Omer, Ol Malchus Shamayim.

Comment: I, for one, am not a fan of *lazy* gematria answers. This one is a gematria-inspired teaching that you cited a source for. That makes it a good answer, not a lazy one.

Comment: Paging @HodofHod.